# 404 page url link to custom domain on heroku ghost blog

Tags: heroku, ghost-blog

I have deployed a `Ghost` blog on `heroku`. The app has the url `app.herokuapp.com`. I have setup a custom domain to point to this `mydomain.com`.

Things work fine in normal access conditions. However, when the user hits a 404 page `mydomain.com/xyz`, it takes me to the 404 page and then there is a link to the `front page`.

A click on this link leads me to the heroku app url(`app.herokuapp.com`) rather than my custom url(`mydomain.com`).

Please let me know how do I point it to the front page of my custom domain `mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can serve a custom error page on Heroku, and you can point it anywhere you'd like.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages